# T-SQL: Update first row of recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query (A) that can returns multiple rows in date order:

```
SELECT encounter_id, department_id, effective_time
FROM   adt
WHERE  event_type IN (1,3,7)
ORDER BY effective_time
```

I have another query (B) that returns a single row:

```
SELECT encounter_id, department_id, arrival_time
FROM   ed
WHERE  event_type = 50
```

I would like to join the query B to query A, in such a way that query B's single row will be associated with query A's *first* record.

I realize that I could do this with a CURSOR, but I was hoping to use T-SQL row_number() function.

Comment: Is the data in resultset A in anyway related to the result in B? Furthermore, What/Which fields in resultset A do you want to Update?

Comment: Please show us what you would want the resulting dataset to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer:

```
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY encounter_id ORDER BY encounter_id, effective_time) row.
```

Unfortunately, the database has data-quality issues that prevent me from approaching the solution this way.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if i got the question right. 
Let me know if the below solution is different than what you were expecting

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT   TOP 1
         encounter_id, department_id, effective_time 
    FROM     adt 
    WHERE    event_type IN (1,3,7) 
    ORDER BY effective_time 
)adt1,
(
    SELECT   encounter_id, department_id, arrival_time 
    FROM     ed 
    WHERE    event_type = 50 
) ed1
```

then you can join both the tables as per your need, using WHERE clause

Regards,
Niyaz